# Ruby on Rails - How would I add a image uploader to the simple_form Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm creating a basic house listing page to get to grips with Rails and I'm trying to work out how I would add a image file uploader to a simple_form gem on Ruby on Rails.

Currently, I have a basic form which asks for a title, price and description, whilst I was creating the form I added an input field for image but instead of an input field, I would like to allow a user to add an image file which would be added to the listing with house.image

My code is as follows:

index.html.erb -

```
<p><%= link_to "Add a House", new_house_path %></p>

<% @houses.each do |house| %>

  <div class="house">
    <p><%= house.image %></p>
    <h2><%= house.title %></h2>
    <h2><%= house.price %></h2>
    <p><%= house.description %></p>
  </div>
<% end %>

<p><%= paginate @houses %></p>
```

house.rb -

```
class House < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :title, presence: true
    validates :price, presence: true
    validates :description, presence: true
    validates :image, presence: true
end
```

houses_controller.rb -

```
class HousesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @houses = House.page(params[:page]).per(20).order(created_at: :desc)
  end

  def new
    @house = House.new
  end

  def create
    @house = House.new(params.require(:house).permit(:title, :price, :description, :image))
  if @house.save
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    render "new"
  end
  end

end
```

new.html.erb -

```
<%= simple_form_for @house do |form| %>
 <%= form.input :title, label: "House title" %>
 <%= form.input :price, label: "House price" %>
 <%= form.input :description, label: "Describe your house" %>
 <%= form.input :image, label: "Image of house" %>
 <%= form.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: refer to this it may help [https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Adding-custom-input-components

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to change:

```
<%= form.input :image, label: "Image of house" %>
```

to

```
<%= form.input :image, as: :file, label: "Image of house" %>
```

This will create a standard HTML file input field which allows your users to select local files for upload. There are information about this and other field types available [Simple Form input field types](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#available-input-types-and-defaults-for-each-column-type).

Additionally, you will want to consider a gem such as [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) or Carrierwave to handle receiving files on the server (in the model).

And if you really want a custom input type in simple_form, you can read about how to implement that in the simple_form github repo under "Custom Inputs" -- this would NOT be necessary for uploading an image. It would be syntactic sugar for your code.

Comment: Thank you, I've added the form.input and that works however its not displaying the image yet, I've added the Paperclip gem to my site but I'm not sure how to implement it.

Comment: Are you trying to display the image in the browser/client prior to upload? If so, the most common way to handle that would be a JavaScript solution (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded). The Paperclip Github repo has some good documentation and a decent wiki for server side receipt and processing of files.

Answer (score 0):

For image upload you can use[paperclip](https://github.com/markevans/dragonfly)

[1](https://github.com/markevans/dragonfly): https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip or [dragonfly](https://github.com/markevans/dragonfly)

Comment: I honestly advise to not use dragonfly. This gem is just pain in the a%%.